# ChromeDriver Quits Unexpectedly

Tags: python, selenium

While trying to learn more about Python, I tried to write a program that would, when given a link, perform an action on the web. I am using the selenium Module, and from it webdriver. The current code looks like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

def supremeTest():
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    browser.get('http://www.google.com')
    linkElem = browser.find_element_by_name("q")
    type(linkElem)
    linkElem.click()
```

The problem, however, lies in that when I change `webdriver.Firefox()` to `.Chrome()` the program opens a Chrome page, then exits before any action is completed.

I am wondering why this is so, and I am using python3, and I do have the latest version of ChromeDriver. I have looked at the help section of ChromeDriver, but from what I was looking at, there was nothing of help there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because selenium by default provide the driver for firefox but not for chrome. if you look at the method calls firefox can be called with 0 arguments.

```
webdriver.Firefox()
```

but not chrome method ,it will take a argument called executable_path

```
webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='<path>')
```

so, to run chrome from selenium you need to download the chrome webdriver from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/). and keep the file path in the  it will work fine. Since, you already downloaded the webdriver, please specify the **path** in the method call of chrome().Like this

```
path_to_chromedriver = 'C:/python34/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe'
browser2 = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path_to_chromedriver)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: So once I download the webdriver, in the "path" section I would just put the location of the downloaded file?

Comment: @user3194722  Yep. that's what you need to do .